# How to use line feeds in CSV file?

Tags: php, excel, csv

I have an excel file that I converted to a CSV so it could be parsed in PHP.  However, for some reason the cells in excel only have Carriage Returns (\r) and no Line Feeds (\n).  I need line feeds in the csv or else the PHP parses everything in one line, which it shouldn't do.

Is there a way to add line feeds to an excel/csv file?

Thanks!

EDIT: It would seem as though I was exporting the file as the wrong csv—I didn't do Windows Comma Separated.  Thanks for the answers guys.

Comment: How about replacing all `\r` with `\n` in the file/contents before parsing it?

Comment: It shouldn't be that way. I just used Excel to export a CSV file and it lines were separated by newlines.

Comment: How are you converting the Excel file to CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you read in your CSV file, do:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
```

Then set it to `false` right after reading the file.

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings):

> This enables PHP to interoperate with Macintosh systems, but defaults
>   to Off, as there is a very small performance penalty when detecting
>   the EOL conventions for the first line, and also because people using
>   carriage-returns as item separators under Unix systems would
>   experience non-backwards-compatible behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to handle it. An easy one in PHP would be to just replace `\r` with `\n` before processing it:

```
// Load the whole data file as a string
$data = file_get_contents("yourcsv.csv");
$data = str_replace("\r","\n", $data);

// use str_getcsv() in PHP 5.3+ to parse it to an array
$csv_array = str_getcsv($data);
```